# input string was not in a correct format - insert in database

Tags: c#

When I introduce nume (means firstname) and prenume (means lastname) I got a error. Strange is that when name and prenume have int values, the program works. Please I need help

```
float medie = (float) Suma / numar_materii;
SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString());
connection.Open();
const string sql = @"INSERT INTO Users (Nume,Prenume,Medie) VALUES (@Nume ,@Prenume,@Medie)";
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, connection);
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Nume", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = namee.Text }) ;
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Prenume", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Value = Prenume.Text});
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Medie", SqlDbType.Real) { Value = medie });
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I got Input string was not in a correct format after the executenonquery

Comment: if this only works with int-values i'd guess the columns 'Nume','Prenume' are using the wrong datatype. can you share some details about the table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that `SQLiteCommand` does not have a constructor that takes `SqlDbType` as an argument. Therefore the constructor `SQLiteParameter(string parameterName, object value)` is chosen.

`SqlDbType.NVarChar` is converted into the corresponding `Int32` value (in this case 12) and the `DbType` of the param is automatically resolved to `Int32.DbType` as Enums in C# are just collections of named number-constants.

In the initializer you change the value of your parameter with a value of type `string`, SQLite cannot convert the new value to an `Int32` and throws a `FormatException`.

You can resolve the issue by using `DbType` instead of `SqlDbType`

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Nume", DbType.String) { Value = namee.Text });
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Prenume", DbType.String) { Value = Prenume.Text });
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Medie", DbType.Double) { Value = medie });
```

or by letting the SQLiteParameter choose the correct `DbType` for you

```
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Nume", namee.Text));
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Prenume", Prenume.Text));
command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Medie", medie));
```